# Unable to deploy WAR file in Wildfly Server - Scan found incompletely copied file content for deployment

Tags: java, grails, jboss, war, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy a WAR file, which I made in grails with the `grails war`command (55 MB), to a Wildfly 8 server. I use the scp command `scp schedulingAPI-0.1.war user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/user/wildfly-8.0.0.CR1/standalone/deployments/ whereafter the file`schedulingAPI-0.1.war.isdeploying`is present on the server. After a few minutes, the file`schedulingAPI-0.1.war.failed` appears on the server.

This is an output of my log file:

```
2014-04-02 15:15:04,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015009: Scan found incompletely copied file content for deployment /home/user/wildfly-8.0.0.CR1/standalone/deployments/schedulingAPI-0.1.war. Deployment changes will not be processed until all content is complete.
2014-04-02 15:37:04,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015009: Scan found incompletely copied file content for deployment /home/user/wildfly-8.0.0.CR1/standalone/deployments/schedulingAPI-0.1.war. Deployment changes will not be processed until all content is complete.
2014-04-02 15:53:15,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015009: Scan found incompletely copied file content for deployment /home/user/wildfly-8.0.0.CR1/standalone/deployments/schedulingAPI-0.1.war. Deployment changes will not be processed until all content is complete.
```

I already tried the suggestion in [this thread](http://www.kevinhooke.com/2012/07/25/deploymentscanner-timeouts-on-openshift-jboss-as7/) to add the attribute `deployment-timeout="2400"` to `<deployment-scanner>` in the `/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was apparently with the mysql configuration (tried with tomcat server which gave me more log information)

Answer (score 1):

I have just come around this problem: file was too big to be completely transferred between deployment scanner polls and hence marked corrupt by Jboss.

My .war file jumped from 7.5M to 18M and this started happening.

In the end, increasing deployment scanner **scan interval** value from 5000ms to 15000ms helped, so I'd suggest that (please mind it is not **deployment timeout**)

[image: JBoss management screen]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure timeout 2400 is enough? 
Deployment should be started after upload of your war file.

Maybe try to execute this command after uploading schedulingAPI-0.1.war:

```
ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx 'rm -fr /home/user/wildfly-8.0.0.CR1/standalone/deployments/schedulingAPI-0.1.war.failed'
```

BTW. you can update wildfly to final version :)

Answer (score 0):

I have experience this before when i try to send the war file directly to deployment over the network. You will have to restart the service if this happens.

Try and avoid this if you have a slow network. If you must, don't worry, just restart the service afterwards